# Remove lines in a file that do not have specified patterns in particular columns

Tags: perl, file, replace, grep

I have a tab-delimited text file.  I have split this into columns.  Each of the first 2 columns contains an ID number.

I want to keep all lines with ID number starting with P or Q, and remove any other lines where column 1 or 2 has any other ID or is blank.

eg. so columns to be kept will be like this:  P12345 or Q12345.  Columns to get rid of will be GAG123, CH123 etc.  or just blank.

I can't work out how to do this.  I have tried splitting lines into arrays and grep /^[PQ]/elements [0] and [1], and various other things, but I must be doing something wrong.

I've tried the follwoing code below from TLP, but it won't work, I know I must be doing something fundamentally wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl  

use warnings;
use strict;

open(FILE,"<myfile.txt"); 
my @LINES = <FILE>; 
open(my $outfile, '>', 'changedtxt');
my @wanted;

while (<FILE>) {
    my @fields = split('\t', $_);
    if ( $fields[0] =~ /^[PQ]/ and $fields[1] =~ /^[PQ]/ ) {
        push @wanted, $_;  
        print {$outfile} $_;    
    }
}
exit:
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: what code have you got so far?

Comment: What if one ID begins with a P or Q, but the other ID doesnt?

Comment: Since you slurp the file into `@LINES`, the while loop does not run. If you remove that line, it should work. Although you do not need to explicitly open the files, just use the shell redirection, e.g. `script.pl input.txt > output.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @wanted;
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = split /\t/, $_;
    if ( $fields[0] =~ /^[PQ]/ or $fields[1] =~ /^[PQ]/ ) {
        push @wanted, $_;
    }
}
```

If you want both IDs to begin with P or Q, exchange `or` for `and`.

If you simply want to move the wanted lines to another file, simply do:

```
perl -wnae 'print if (($F[0] =~ /^[PQ]/) or ($F[1] =~ /^[PQ]/))' input.txt > output.txt
```

Or as a script, use with `script.pl input.txt > output.txt`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while (<>) {
    my @fields = split(/\t/, $_);
    print if ( $fields[0] =~ /^[PQ]/ and $fields[1] =~ /^[PQ]/ );

}
```

Note that you can't use `'\t'` as a split pattern.

Comment: With this code, you get no output. You just get the lines you want in the `@wanted` array. If you want output, you have to add it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add my aditional code, but it added my comment before I got chance to do it!

Comment: appended to my question above now

Comment: You should also define the filehandle.

Comment: Oh by the way, do your fields contain any whitespace? It might be prudent to split explicitly on tab.

Comment: @Dimitar Yes, it is not a complete script, just adding on to whatever method he used before to get the fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk to print out the records where the first or second field begins with P or Q:

```
awk -F'\t' '$1~/[PQ].*/ || $2~/[PQ].*/ {print}'  file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in one line:

```
cat yourfile.txt | perl -e 'while (<>) { print if m/^[PQ]/xmsi && m/\t+[PQ]/xmsi }
```